# when i change my virtual device to render in android studio my components get rearranged

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio, virtual-device-manager

[This is Nexus 6 virtual device with which I have rendered my activity_.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/22VIe.jpg)

[This is the device when I change it automatically edits the components(for example the CLEAR button in the app)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xX3d3.jpg)

Following is my activity_main.xml file which I have used in the project:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:weightSum="1"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="arial"
        android:text="Enter Numbers"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"/>
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/text1"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/text1"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:text="1" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/b1"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/b1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/b1"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:text="2" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/b2"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/b2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/b2"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:text="3" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/b3"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/b3"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/b3"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:text="4" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/b1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:text="5" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/b5"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/b5"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/b5"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:text="6" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@id/b6"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/b6"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/b6"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:text="7" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b8"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@id/b7"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/b7"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/b7"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:text="8" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b9"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/b5"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:text="9" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b0"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/b9"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/b9"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/b9"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:text="0" />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/b10"
            android:text="."
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/b0"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/b0"
            android:layout_alignTop="@id/b0"
            android:clickable="true"          />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/b11"
            android:text="Clear"
            android:layout_alignTop="@id/b10"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/b10"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/b10"
            android:clickable="true"
            />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/b12"
            android:text="+"
            android:layout_below="@+id/b9"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/b13"
            android:text="-"
            android:layout_alignTop="@id/b12"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/b12"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/b12"
            android:clickable="true"
            />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/b14"
            android:text="*"
            android:layout_alignTop="@id/b13"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/b13"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/b13"
            android:clickable="true"
            />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/b15"
            android:text="/"
            android:layout_alignTop="@id/b14"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/b14"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/b14"
            android:clickable="true"
            />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/b16"
            android:text="="
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/b13"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/b15"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/b15" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:id="@+id/text2"
            android:hint="Result"
            android:layout_below="@+id/b16"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/b16"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/b16"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/et1"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/et1" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

When I switch between devices I want my design to be displayed the same way as it is displayed in Nexus 6.
Please help me out with the above issues. I have surfed the net but I'm not finding any appropriate answer to resolve my query.

Comment: Please edit your xml following my example from button b7 to the end: indentation should be smaller.

Comment: Difference devices have different layout densities. Therefore, if you have different `res/layout` folders in your project or are running a device with a different density, then yes, your components will be re-arranged.

Comment: yup!! thankyou for your advice